# Is CSRF protection required for sensitive GET requests with CORS enabled?

Tags: csrf, cors

Based on [other questions](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/115794/should-i-use-csrf-protection-for-get-requests?newreg=54a3511667614bc5abbf2994a7d18ea1), it seems protecting GET resources with CSRF tokens is useless. However, that quickly becomes untrue when CORS gets thrown into [the mix](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/191777/csrf-protection-is-needed-for-get-requests)

I have a server domain `server.com` and a UI app at `client.com`. The `server.com` domain handles user auth and sets a session cookie under the `server.com` domain. It also has a rest-like endpoint that serves GET requests at `/user_data` and returns sensitive user data to users with a valid session. The 3rd party UI at `client.com` needs access to the user_data in an AJAX call, so `CORS` is enabled at the `/user_data` endpoint for the origin domain `client.com` via `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`.

The endpoint in question has no side effects, although it serves sensitive data to a 3rd party. Do I need to implement some CSRF token protection for the endpoint? Could the user_data be read by a compromised `client.com` webpage (via persistent XSS)? If so, can I use a ***query param*** mechanism of `CSRF token` exchange? The way I understand it, it's the only option, because the `client.com` cannot read csrf tokens stored in a `server.com` cookies. However [OWASP guidelines](https://owasp.org/www-project-cheat-sheets/cheatsheets/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html) state that:

> Make sure that the token is not leaked in the server logs, or in the URL.

If that's also a problem, how can I secure my application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> it seems protecting GET resources with CSRF tokens is useless.

It's not useless if you have state-changing GET request (which you shouldn't have, but it does happen).

> Do I need to implement some CSRF token protection for the endpoint?

No, requests which do not change state do not need CSRF protection (they may need proper authorization though).

> Could the user_data be read by a compromised client.com webpage (via persistent XSS)?

Yes, if you allow `client.com` to read data from `server.com` via CORS, then a compromised `client.com` can read that data as well.

> If so, can I use a query param mechanism of CSRF token exchange? The way I understand it, it's the only option, because the client.com cannot read csrf tokens stored in a server.com cookies.

No, CSRF protection wouldn't help. `client.com` can't read the cookie from `server.com`, but it *can* read anything on `client.com`. And you would need `client.com` to know the CSRF token to be able to send requests with it to `server.com`.

> how can I secure my application?

Do not let `client.com` be compromised. There's no other way to prevent `client.com` (compromised) from accessing data on `server.com` while also permitting `client.com` (not compromised) to access data on `server.com` because those two can't be distinguished.

> Make sure that the token is not leaked in the server logs, or in the URL.

You can send the token in a custom HTTP header to prevent this. But see above as to why it won't help if `client.com` is already compromised.